# Different Resumes versions on the Web (one is "fake")

Tags: resume, hiring-process, recruitment, contracts

I'll start by saying I have a computer science degree, and my first job I got was with a consulting firm who offered to train me in the relevant technologies (under contract). I signed the 16 month contract which read, after my training I will be marketed to external clients and go through the Hiring Process looking for C2C contracts.

Unbeknown to me until after I signed the contract and talked with other people who were going through the program I would be Marketed with **5 yrs exp** when in reality actually was I fresher.

I have made many connections with recruiters along the way (with them thinking I have 5+ yrs exp). Now that my contract is coming to an end, I will be marketing myself and I don't feel right lying on my resume so now my Resume will look a little different with less years experience.

My Question is, with all the Recruiters I've made contact with should I just forget about them? How can I elegantly handle the situation of sending an "updated" resume, with less yrs experience than the one they have on file? What if I do send that resume, and the company I was under contract is essentially outed, could that effect me negatively?

Comment: Tough problem dealing with recruiters, maybe even tougher if you ever want to work for any of the clients that you consulted for.

Comment: It was only 2 clients, and I could stay where I'm at now when the contract is up but I don't plan on doing that.

Comment: Depending on your locale, your first company's actions may constitute fraud. An actual lawyer can say for sure, which may limit your (legal) options about how to continue.

Comment: @Telastyn I can honestly say for a fact that won't happen. Different state, too many layers in that contract job, and the project was completed without hitch. It wouldn't fall on my shoulders anyway.

Comment: Does the "years of experience" have a concrete definition in this case, e.g. if you work for company A from beg of 2008 until end of 2012, then that is 5 years experience in a concrete way, but often "years of experience" is stated without definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just write (tell) the actual facts. If anyone notices the discrepancy and asks, tell him/her the truth as you did here. You did nothing wrong. The only downside here is that you put your former employer in a bad light, so be delicate about that.

As far as they are available to you for editing, replace the incorrect on-line versions. If you have sent a resume to recruiter X, next time you need him, send him an updated version. You have made another career step so the previous ones are out-of-date anyway.

Although nothing really ever disappears from the internet, the old ones will fade away over time.

And after another 5 years no one will know ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your response Jan, all of those resumes have already been removed from the job board sites, the only ones I am worried about is the one's in Recruiters Databases. I don't think I'm going to have to worry much, its really only 2 people in mind. I actually worked as a temp under this one agency in a previous job for 3 months, and came in contact with them again with my 'new' resume, and they had no idea who I was. Another agency had my old (completely different) and new resume in front of them and brought it up, all I said was this is my most updated resume and they left it at that.